# How to get XSL to ignore xmlns short name

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I don't know too much about XSL but have managed to format XML coming from 3rd party web services using XSL without too much trouble. But the other day, a site that used to work stopped working. I discovered that they made a tiny change to the XML returned by the web service. This is what used to work (greatly simplified):

**Update:** I see the problem now, but I don't have a solution. The problem is with xsl:if test="@xsi:type='r0:CreditTx'". Change every "r0" to "s0" in the XSL, and it does not work.

I have replaced my original code with a working example:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="unicode"?>
<MyResp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:r0="http://www.foo.com/2.1/schema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <r0:creditVendReceipt receiptNo="1234567890">
        <r0:transactions>
            <r0:tx xsi:type="r0:CreditTx">
                <r0:amt value="100" />
            </r0:tx>
        </r0:transactions>
    </r0:creditVendReceipt>
</MyResp>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:r0="http://www.foo.com/2.1/schema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body >
            <xsl:for-each select="MyResp/r0:creditVendReceipt/r0:transactions/r0:tx">
              <xsl:if test="@xsi:type='r0:CreditTx'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="r0:amt/@value"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired HTML:

```
<html xmlns:r0="http://www.foo.com/2.1/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
        100
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem came when the web service changed the xmlns' short name "a" to "a0" (it now sends xmlns:a0="http://mysite.com/webservice/1.0/schema"); the namespace and everything else is the same. I have to change "a" to "a0" in the XSL for it to work (i.e. "GetInfoResp/a0:userName"). The problem is that the short name sent by the service changes from time to time. (In the real app there are a lot of name spaces, and the short names are even changing between the various requests.)

I thought the short name was just to make the XML shorter and easier to read, and that the actual name isn't significant (betwen the XML and the XSL; within the XSL obviously it has to match).

Can I get the XSL to ignore the short name in the XML, and just use its own short name?

Sorry if this was answered before; I looked thru the other questions and didn't see this specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

The "short name" is called a namespace prefix -- and you don't have to change the namespace prefix in the transformation -- in fact it may be completely different from any prefix that could be used in the XML document.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xYz="http://mysite.com/webservice/1.0/schema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xYz">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body >
          <xsl:value-of select="GetInfoResp/xYz:userName"/>
        </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces exactly the same result as this transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a0="http://mysite.com/webservice/1.0/schema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="a0">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body >
          <xsl:value-of select="GetInfoResp/a0:userName"/>
        </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both transformations, when applied on this XML document** (what is provided in the question is severely malformed and had to be corrected):

```
<GetInfoResp xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a0="http://mysite.com/webservice/1.0/schema">
 <a0:userName>Joe</a0:userName>
</GetInfoResp>
```

**produce the same result**:

```
<html>
   <body>Joe</body>
</html>
```

**Lesson to learn**:

What matters is the namespace, not the prefix used to shorthand it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to keep the code short and removed the bits that weren't directly relevant; I accidentally removed a bit too much. What you say was exactly my understanding. The problem is that it definitely is not working when the only difference is the prefix (sorry I forgot the terminalogy). Everything else is exactly the same. Is it possible that the software I am using is doing this wrong? I am using VB.Net's XslTransform (.Net 4.0).

Comment: @user2176753, Please, *edit* the question and provide a complete (but small) code example, that others could reproduce. Without doing this people can't help you.

Comment: I am guessing that the problem is that xsl:if test="@xsi:type='r0:CreditTx' is doing a pure string comparison, when I actually need something to compare name spaces. Is that correct? I don't know enough about XSL to figure out how to do this. I'd apreciate any help.

Comment: @user2176753, Yes, this is definitely a problem, but I don't see such a problem described in your current question.

Comment: The XML I am formatting can have hundreds of transactions of 20 or so different types (e.g. CreditTx) that need to be formatted slightly differently depending on the type, hence I need to test the type. If it is sometimes r0:CreditTx and sometimes r:CreditTx (and the prefix could in theory be anything), is there any way that I can expand the prefix to the full namespace before doing a string compare? Or does XSL have a clever way of doing this?

Comment: And just to be clear, the prefix will not change inside one XML stream, but between different web services that were developed by different people, but using the same standard specification. I am trying to avoid having to maintain different XSL files for different servers, when the only difference is in the prefixes.

Comment: @user2176753, Please, *edit* the question (or better ask a new question as the current one is completely answered) and provide small but complete: source XML document, exact wanted result, rules/constraints that the transformation must implement.